# CSS transition for scrolling div to div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a site and would like to use the feature displayed on this site: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB078J269

Specifically, how the scrolling temporarily locks and forces the user to read what's in the div before scrolling forward.

I've tried css transitions that start from div to div but have been unsuccessful. I've also tried:

```
.div_container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

My index.html for each container looks something like this:

```
<div id="content-container-1" class="content-container">(#content...)</div>
<div id="content-container-2" class="content-container">(#content...)</div>
<div id="content-container-3" class="content-container">(#content...)</div>
<div id="content-container-4" class="content-container">(#content...)</div>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) might be what you're looking for. It's the jQuery script used on that site.

Comment: @user3007294 or you might prefer http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ if you are looking for compatibility with old browsers such as IE 8, 9, Opera 12... and other options such as horizontal scrolling or continuous vertical scrolling.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for months. I tried to make my own and abandoned my project because of it (for the best it was hideous). 

If you want to see how it shouldn't be done. Check here: http://drbr.co.uk/old/
Thanks Bob!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the locked scrolling is done via jQuery, but the `div` height can be accomplished by doing the following:

1. set `html` and `body` to:

   position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
2. Wrap your `content-container`s in another div and make then count how many pages it has inside of it. For example, if it has 4 pages then set its height to 400%. Make sure to do the position absolute thing in that too.
3. Then set your `content-container`s to:

   position:relative;
   float:left;
   clear:both;
   width:100%;
   height:25%;

And taadaa! You should be golden.

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice alternative to the onepage-scroll plugin.